# more efficient way to select image pixel that satisfy multiple color conditions

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

i want to select fire pixels in each video frame using Lab, RGB, and YCbCr color rule.

i've tried with the code below, but the video output turns out really laggy. i believe this caused by iterating through pixel frame with loop. i wonder if there is more efficient way to do this (e.g. with numpy).

here is my code:

```
# COLOR SEGMENTATION
lab_convert = convert_lab(frame)
L, a, b = cv2.split(lab_convert)
L_mean, a_mean, b_mean = cv2.mean(lab_convert)[:-1]
                
rgb_convert = convert_rgb(frame)
R, G, B = cv2.split(rgb_convert)
R_mean = cv2.mean(R)[0]

ycbcr_convert = convert_ycbcr(frame)
Y, Cb, Cr = cv2.split(ycbcr_convert)

height, width, _ = frame.shape
frame_copy = frame.copy()

for y in range(height):
   for x in range(width):
      # rules
      lab_rule_1 = L[y, x] >= L_mean
      lab_rule_2 = a[y, x] >= a_mean
      lab_rule_3 = b[y, x] >= b_mean
      lab_rule_4 = b[y, x] >= a_mean
      lab_satisfied = lab_rule_1 and lab_rule_2 and lab_rule_3 and lab_rule_4

      rgb_rule_1 = R[y, x] > G[y, x] > B[y, x]
      rgb_rule_2 = R[y, x] >= R_mean
      rgb_satisfied = rgb_rule_1 and rgb_rule_2

      ycbcr_rule_1 = (R[y, x] >= G[y, x]) and (G[y, x] > B[y, x])
      ycbcr_rule_2 = (R[y, x] > 190) and (G[y, x] > 100) and (B[y, x] < 140)
      ycbcr_rule_3 = Y[y, x] >= Cb[y, x]
      ycbcr_rule_4 = Cr[y, x] >= Cb[y, x]
      ycbcr_satisfied = (ycbcr_rule_1 and ycbcr_rule_2) or (ycbcr_rule_3 and ycbcr_rule_4)

      # check if pixel satisfies all rules (per color space)
      if lab_satisfied:
         lab_convert[y, x] = 255
      else:
         lab_convert[y, x] = 0

      if rgb_satisfied:
         rgb_convert[y, x] = 255
      else:
         rgb_convert[y, x] = 0

      if ycbcr_satisfied:
         ycbcr_convert[y, x] = 255
      else:
         ycbcr_convert[y, x] = 0

      # check if pixel satisfies all rules
      if lab_satisfied or rgb_satisfied or ycbcr_satisfied:
         frame_copy[y, x] = 255
      else:
         frame_copy[y, x] = 0
```

Comment: Use vectorized operations. For example, Numpy lets you do `L >= L_mean`, which will do the comparison on all the pixels in a single call to an optimized function, returning an array of booleans.

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve] (you're missing imports and there are several calls to undefined functions, such as `convert_lab`), including a simple input image.

Comment: Here's a quick draft replacing those nested loops: https://pastebin.com/DXrxmf17 Gets the same result as your code, but instead of 4 seconds it takes 10 milliseconds. Once you update your post as instructed above, and I'll write up an answer with some explanations.

Comment: @DanMašek can't thank you enough, appreciate your help!

Comment: Please don’t add an answer to the question. Put that in the answer box below. It is fine to answer your own question. But the question box should only contain an question. You’ll be able to accept your own answer, marking the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved!**

shoutout to @dan-mašek for helping me to solve this problem. here is the code: https://pastebin.com/DXrxmf17

```
# COLOR SEGMENTATION
lab_convert = convert_lab(frame)
L, a, b = cv2.split(lab_convert)
L_mean, a_mean, b_mean = cv2.mean(lab_convert)[:-1]

rgb_convert = convert_rgb(frame)
R, G, B = cv2.split(rgb_convert)
R_mean = cv2.mean(R)[0]

ycbcr_convert = convert_ycbcr(frame)
Y, Cb, Cr = cv2.split(ycbcr_convert)

lab_rule_1 = L >= L_mean
lab_rule_2 = a >= a_mean
lab_rule_3 = b >= b_mean
lab_rule_4 = b >= a_mean
lab_satisfied = lab_rule_1 & lab_rule_2 & lab_rule_3 & lab_rule_4

rgb_rule_1 = (R > G) & (G > B) # No chaining in numpy
rgb_rule_2 = R >= R_mean
rgb_satisfied = rgb_rule_1 & rgb_rule_2

ycbcr_rule_1 = (R >= G) & (G > B)
ycbcr_rule_2 = (R > 190) & (G > 100) & (B < 140)
ycbcr_rule_3 = Y >= Cb
ycbcr_rule_4 = Cr >= Cb
ycbcr_satisfied = (ycbcr_rule_1 & ycbcr_rule_2) | (ycbcr_rule_3 & ycbcr_rule_4)


lab_convert = np.uint8(lab_satisfied) * 255
rgb_convert = np.uint8(rgb_satisfied) * 255
ycbcr_convert = np.uint8(ycbcr_satisfied) * 255

combined = lab_convert | rgb_convert | ycbcr_convert
frame_copy = np.repeat(combined[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
```